# Magento2 PHP CodeSniffer - "Use of protected class members is discouraged"

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

My question is - why the usage of protected members in class in Magento 2 is discouraged?

I looked into other questions that ask about warnings of the PHP CodeSniffer for Magento 2, but nobody addressed this specific warning - "Use of protected class members is discouraged".

In my understanding avoiding the usage of protected members conflicts with the idea of inheritance. That is, if I want to extend the functionality of the protected method and therefore I might need to touch the protected member, I wont be able to do that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware some protected class members will need to be protected. I have seen solutions like this applied to phpcs, basically removing the warning:

https://github.com/eMerchantPay/magento2-emp-plugin/blob/master/.phpcs.xml

Notice these standards have not been updated in 4 months and are not yet working with the latest version of Code Sniffer, so I'm pretty sure an update is due.